# How to connect to Azure Ubuntu VM MySQL server from local machine MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mysql-database

I did set INBOUND PORT RULES in Azure. but still it is not working.
[image]

I want to connect this with MySQL workbench and with google VMs it works. If you can please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Some possible reasons you might consider in this case:

- If you can connect to google VM with MySQL Workbench, I suppose the local firewall is open for the destination SQL server ports.
- Check the NSG both VM and subnet level.
- Check if the SQL server configuration is well, especially the SQL server port, options for connectivity. You can get more references about [Connect to a SQL Server Virtual Machine on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-connect#manual).
- Check if the port 3306 is listening on the Azure VM by using `netstat -anpl | grep 3306`. If not, you can check if your VM firewall blocks this access.

If the issue still exists, you can add more details about your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Firewall Rule to allow inbound traffic from the Public IP address where MySQL Workbench is being launched (See Image).

[image]